# Compare two one row PySpark dataframes and modify them?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I can't find a Sparkified-way to do this, and was hoping some of you data experts out there might be able to help:

I have two dataframes:

1

```
item_list
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0]
```

2

```
item_list
[3,0,0,4,2,6,1,0,0]
```

I want to return a new dataframe like this. For every non-zero in DF 2, replace it with 1 if DF 1 is non-zero at that index and return a new dataframe.

Result:

```
item_list
[3,1,1,4,2,6,1,1,0]
```

This is fairly easy to do in standard python. How can I do this in Spark?

Comment: Is item list an arraytype column in your dataframes and what is your spark version?

Comment: Yes, it's an ArrayType(IntegerType) and I'm using Spark 2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implemented the below code in Scala syntactically should be much difference from PySpark
you can also take help of the inline code comments which explains the code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object JoinDF {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess

    import spark.implicits._
    var df1 = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0).toDF("col1")  // 1st Dataframe
    var df2 = List(3, 0, 0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 0, 0).toDF("col2")  // 2nd Dataframe

    df1 = df1.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())  // Add row num to 1st DF
    df2 = df2.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())  // Add row num to 2nd DF

    val df3 = df2.join(df1, df1("id") === df2("id"))    // perform inner join 
      .drop("id")  // drop the id column
      .withColumn("eval", when($"col1" === $"col2", $"col2")  // if equal assign col2
        .otherwise( 
          when( $"col2" === lit(0), 1)  // if col2 is 0 assign 1
            .otherwise($"col2")                          // else set to col2
        ))

    df3.show()

  }

}
```